# How can I get Basic authorization header and authenticate it for API by using PHP

Tags: php, http-headers, authorization, slim

How can I get Basic authorization header and authenticate it for API by using PHP. I had created a unique key which is encoded and stored in database. I am using **Slim Framework** for rest API.

I can get the header by using `$request->headers();` in Slim Framework. It returns all the headers specified, but how do i check that key with my database token.

Is there any proper way to do this?

Comment: 1 code can say more than a thousand words.. Add a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried $request->getHeader[$nameOfHeaderKey]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this in Slim Framework 3:

I added the Middleware to all of the requests and checked the Authorization header for certain string and if the Authorization header is not set or doesnt match my string i just return 400 HTTP code.

```
$app->add(function($request,$response,$next){
$authorization_header = $request->getHeader("Authorization");

if(empty($authorization_header) || ($authorization_header[0]!="test")){ //you can check the header for a certain string or you can check if what is in the Authorization header exists in your database

    return $response->withStatus(400);
}

$response = $next($request,$response);

return $response;

});
```

Comment: you should use the slim response for that not header() but ``return $response->withStatus(400);``

Comment: yes, you're right...thanks..i'm going to edit the answer

Comment: This only works on NGINX since apache intercepts the authorization header, just an fyi